# How to add annotations using OpenLayers mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile, mobile, openlayers

I am using Jquery mobile along with OpenLayers mobile.

I want to give users the ability to draw features like lines and polygons. I would also like to give them the ability to "write" an annotation and place the text at a point on the map.

Does anyone have a small example of how to add text to the map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use some JavaScript and HTML text input to achieve the text input.
To save your annotations you can try exporting and importing [geojson](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Format/GeoJSON-js.html)
You can set text on a map marker: `marker.icon.imageDiv.title = 'yourTitleHere';`